# objective-c creating an object from a text file

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, object, text, nsstring

I just succeeded to load a file:

Let's say it has this at the moment:

Map1

Map2

Here is the code for getting the string:

```
NSURL *fileURL=[NSURL fileURLWithPath:@"/Users/Maze.txt"];

NSString *contents =[NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:fileURL encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
NSArray *lines = [[NSArray alloc]init];
lines= [contents componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n"];
for (NSString *s in lines){
    NSLog(@"The content is: %@ \n", s);
}
```

However, I just wanna ask, how can I create an object based on those string?
Let's say I already have a map class, and I want to create an object based on the data on that text file, so now I will have 2 objects, Map1 and Map2.. Is it possible to use the NSString as an object name?

Thanks..

Comment: Do you want to convert the NSString into class like this: NSClassFromString(@"NSButton")

Answer (score 0):

NSDictionary provides a similar method for reading from file : https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDictionary_Class/Reference/Reference.html
Also for NSArray you can get a similar method : https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have a Map class like this:

```
@interface Map : NSObject
@property ( nonatomic, strong ) NSString * name ;
@property ( nonatomic, strong ) NSNumber * latitude ;
@property ( nonatomic, strong ) NSNumber * longitude ;
@end
```

You might have a JSON file like this:

```
[
    { "name":"Map1"; "latitude":41.881944; "longitude":-87.627778 },
    { "name":"Map2"; "latitude":48.8567; "longitude":2.3508 },
]
```

You could get 2 Map instances like this:

```
NSArray * CreateMapsWithContentsOfFileAtURL( NSURL * url )
{
    NSData * data = [ NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:fileURL ] ;
    NSError * error = nil ;
    NSArray * array = [ NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:&error ] ;
    NSArray * maps = [ array collect:^(NSDictionary * dict){
        Map * map = [ [ Map alloc ] init ] ;
        [ map setValuesForKeysWithDictionary:dict ] ;
        return map ;
    }] ;
    return maps ;
}
```

where `-[NSArray collect:]` is provided by

```
@implementation NSArray (Collect)

-(NSArray*)collect:(id (^)(id object))block
{
    if ( !block ) { return nil ; }
    NSMutableArray * result = [ NSMutableArray array ] ;
    for( id object in self )
    {
        id newObject = block( object ) ;
        if ( newObject ) { [ result addObject:newObject ] ; }
    }
    return result ;
}

@end
```